# Passing objects to a laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5, middleware

According to the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware), a middleware may be *parametrised* with static values in the *routes* file:

```
Route::put('post/{id}', ['middleware' => 'role:editor', function ($id) {
    //
}]);
```

What if I need to pass in a service?

---

My motivation for doing this is avoiding Facades because even though they are supposed to be mockable, I am running into problems already at the first try. Mockery/mockery does some crazy eval stuff and I am not wiling to debug that. In essence some class is declared twice and PHP chokes with a fatal error. It happens probably because I am following the example incorrectly, but let us leave it at that. I do not want to rely on Facades.

I do not want to learn about why Facades are awesome, because dependency declaration in constructors is enough to make me happy.

---

I tried following the route action, but I cant not understand what happens in Route::parseAction($action). Where are the middlewares instantiated? Is there a standard way to pass objects to middewares?

Comment: By the way, the facade was not mockable because it had a static method (not my code!) instead of delegating to a service through the facade-accessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a service passed to the middleware you need to **declare it as a dependency of middleware's constructor**. As an example look at the **RedirectIfAuthenticated** middleware that exists by default in Laravel app - it gets fetched the **Guard** object, which is the one you can also access via **Auth** facade.

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
  /**
   * The Guard implementation.
   *
   * @var Guard
   */
  protected $auth;

  /**
   * Create a new filter instance.
   *
   * @param  Guard $auth
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct(Guard $auth)
  {
    $this->auth = $auth;
  }

  //rest of the code
```